# Where do word vectors get computed?

Tags: nlp, spacy

I deal with terms and acronyms, so I am equating a word vector of a term to its acronym's vector. For instance, the word vector of MPH will be the same as Miles Per Hour. However, I do this step as a custom component in the pipeline, specifically before the tagger. I do not see any changes in the assigned vector of an acronym. Am I missing something here?

```
matches = self.matcher(doc)

for match_id, start, end in matches:
    span = doc[start:end]

    print("matched_span: ", span.text)
    #Get string representation
    term = self.abbr_term_dict[span.text]
    term_doc = nlp(term)

    # nlp.vocab.set_vector("MPH", nlp('Miles Per hour').vector)
    # setting the vecor for acronym
    nlp.vocab.set_vector(span.text, term_doc.vector)
```